# Masking dimensions outside of a window

Tags: pytorch

I have a Pytorch tensor `t` of shape `(n, x, y)`, and I'd like to apply a mask such that, for all `y > x + k` (with `k` being a constant), `t[n, x, y] = -inf`.

I believe I can do this with advanced indexing, but can't figure out how.

If not, a simple way to do this is to construct a mask like that with loops (slow, but do it one time and cache it), and then `t += mask`, since `-inf + z == -inf` for all `z`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the condition `y ≥ x` corresponds to the upper triangle, while `y > x` is the strict upper triangle. Therefore `y > x + k` is the upper triangle part with a shift equal to `1 + k`.

You can construct a triangle mask using [`torch.triu`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.triu.html?highlight=upper) which actually allows for a *shift* argument named `diagonal`, referring to the position of the diagonal. Assign the desired value, here `-torch.inf`, using this mask will allow you to obtain the desired result.

Overall it comes down to:

```
>>> m = torch.ones_like(t, dtype=bool).triu(1+k)
>>> t[m] = -torch.inf
```

Alternatively, a one-liner is possible using [`torch.where`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.where.html):

```
>>> torch.where(torch.ones_like(t).bool().triu(1+k), -torch.inf, t)
```

---

Since the mask is equal for all batch elements, you can get away with creating a single 2D mask and masking `t` on its 2nd and 3rd axes:

```
>>> m = torch.ones_like(t[0], dtype=bool).triu(1+k)
>>> t[:,m] = -torch.inf
```

Comment: Thanks! Why did you use `ones` and not `zero`? Do you recommend multiplying by the mask instead of adding it?

Comment: If you use `zeros_like`, your tensor `m` will be filled with zeros, i.e. no point in doing that. You should better mask your tensor `t` with `m` as I did above.

Comment: I intend to use `masked_score = score + mask`: doesn't that require zeros?

Comment: Why do you make it more complex when you can mask the original tensor straight away?

Comment: To cache the mask, and not need to reconstruct it each iteration.  Construct it once, then add it each iteration. Do you disagree?

Comment: Why can't you do that with a masking approach? This seems a bit counterintuitive when thinking about how masking works ..